# How To Sort List based on Dependencies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dependencies, topological-sort

Firstly, i know Topological sort :) But I couldn't solve this problem. I have a dependency based list. for Example;

ID, dependent Ids 
---, ------------ 
[1],[] 
[2],[1] 
[3],[1] 
[4],[1] 
[5],[3] 
[6],[5] 
[7],[2,4,6] 

I want to print list like a this:

1
-2
-3
--5
---6
-4
 
----7

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do 5 and 6 go before 4 in top-to-bottom order?

Comment: @Pointy Because 5 dependent on 3 and 6 dependent on 5. I want to visualize list with dependency.

Comment: @AaronHall I did write some js codes but the result I get, just a list of dependencies.

Comment: @Pointy it's true and 4 can be before 3.